# react-data-grid horizontal scrolling problem

Tags: javascript, react-data-grid

I encountered two buggy scrolling behaviors with react-data-grid. One is the table header's delayed scrolling compared to the table body. The other one is the frozen columns' stuttering behavior. Both are only observed when scrolling with trackpad gestures.
See the comparison scrolling by

**trackpad**

[image]

**scrollbar**

[image]

And try it yourself here - [their example](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/frozen-columns)

I think that these issues are caused by inertial scrolling but I am having trouble finding a way to detect it (I tried lethargy but it does not work as well as it does in its demo) and even if I can, I can't implement it because the callback in onScroll event listener is nested inside the library. For a more detailed problem statement, I have also posted in [react-data-grid github repo](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1386#issuecomment-510099011)

Hope this is making sense. Any help is appreciated!